# ggplot() lines transparency

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, line-plot

How to change the transparency level of lines in `ggplot()` diagram (i.e. histogram, line plot, etc.)?

For instance consider the code below:

```
data <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100,.5,1.2))
data <- melt(data)
colnames(data) <- c("Category", "Intensity")
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Intensity))
p <- p + geom_density(aes(color=Category), size=2, alpha=.4)
print(p)
```

I expected the lines would be transparent (as `alpha=.4`), but they're not.

[image]

Comment: `geom_density` uses alpha for the `fill` aesthetic. If you don't want a fill, use `geom_line(aes(color=Category), stat="density", alpha=0.4)` instead.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Simply following [@baptiste's directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411270/ggplot-lines-transparency/14411354#comment20055398_14411270),

```
data <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100,.5,1.2))
data <- melt(data)
colnames(data) <- c("Category", "Intensity")
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Intensity))
p + geom_line(aes(color=Category), stat="density", linewidth=2, alpha=0.4)
```

[image: Ceci n'est pas une pipe]

Comment: how to do this on other geom? Any idea?

Comment: You should ask a new question. Try to show what you have tried and if possible you should strive to be specific. Cheers!

Comment: In reference to Indranil's question: For opacity - use "alpha=n" where n is from 0 (transparent) to 1 (solid) - available on almost any geom element. Can alternately add opacity to RGB specification in "colour" (or "fill") using "colour=#rrggbbAA" where AA is from 00 (transparent) to FF (solid). (see: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/HEAD/R/aes-colour-fill-alpha.r).